# SAS Two dimensional array with macro variables as dimensions

Tags: multidimensional-array, sas-macro

Can you help for this question please,

How to define two dimensional arrays with flexible dimensions depending on macro variables in SAS?

%LET Dim = &a.*&b.;

ARRAY Spline{&a.,&b.} B1-B&Dim.;

I tried with the above code but it gave these errors:

http://s17.postimg.org/v5nkxw8hb/Sans_titre.png

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. The image is blur.  2. A SAS array must have fixed dimensions and can only be used within data steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a macro variable assingment you can not have a mathematical expression.

So if a = 4 and b = 5

%LET Dim = &a.*&b.;

resolves to DIM = "4*5" as string, but you want 20 instead.

to do this, you have to do the mathematical operation in a datastep:

```
data _null_;
    temp= &a * &b;
    call symputx('DIM', temp);

    ARRAY Spline{&a.,&b.} B1-B&DIM;
run;
```

Also i wonder about your screenshot, it seems that B = 5-1 (as string), so i guess you already did a matehematical operation when assinging b, which failed...
%let b = 5-1; resolves to a string "5-1", not to 4...

so in your example everything resolves to:

```
 ARRAY Spline{4,5-1} B1-B4*5-1;
```

i guess you wanted

```
    ARRAY Spline{4,4} B1-B16;
```

so seperate all mathematical operations in a datastep...

Comment: "%let myDIM = %sysevalf(4*5);" would create a macro var with value "20"